# Go back URL in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, url, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1

How can I get the previous URL visited on the website in Laravel 5.1?

In Laravel 4 I just needed to write it like below:

```
{{ URL::previous() }}
```

Comment: Should be the same, but you could use `Redirect::back()` also

Comment: Oh i wasn't clear.. That Redirect::back() does work in the controller, but not in the blade views!

Comment: Did you try the `URL::previous()` ? Should work in L5 too

Comment: http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.html#method_previous

Comment: Do you have this line in your **config/app.php**:
`'URL'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
`

Answer (score 172, accepted):

The cleanest way seems to be using the `url()` helper:

```
{{ url()->previous() }}
```

---

`URL::previous()` works for me in my Laravel 5.1 project. Here is [Laravel 5.1 doc](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.html#method_previous) for `previous()` method, which is accessible through **URL Facade**.

You can still try alternatives, in your views you can do:

```
{{ redirect()->getUrlGenerator()->previous() }}
```

or:

```
{{ redirect()->back()->getTargetUrl() }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Every example you posted working, don't know why it didn't do before!

Comment: `url()->previous()` a bit cleaner

Comment: It is failing in case if there is server side validation implemented on form.