# Get previous url in laravel

Tags: laravel, url, redirect, back

I am trying to get previous url in laravel, I have tried this code,

```
        echo redirect()->back()->getTargetUrl();
        die();
```

when i simply echo this code, This correctly returns the url, but when i try to save it in some variable, It does not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go back URL in Laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826887/go-back-url-in-laravel-5-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find it in the docs.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#accessing-the-current-url

```php
// Get the current URL without the query string...
echo url()->current();

// Get the current URL including the query string...
echo url()->full();

// Get the full URL for the previous request...
echo url()->previous();
```